# How can I add multiple pre-generated subplots into a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm using this library called [FMSkill](https://dhi.github.io/fmskill/).

One of the method in this library is called [`.plot_timeseries`](https://dhi.github.io/fmskill/api.html?highlight=plot#fmskill.comparison.PointComparer.plot_timeseries)

This method returns an Axes.Subplot object from matplotlib.

I'm trying to use that method to build a Multiplot Figure. I have a list called `comparison` that contains items upon which I can call the `.plot_timeseries()` method.

I've tried something like:

```
import math
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import fmskill as fms

#Code to determine how many subplots in the figure

fig = plt.figure()

if len(comparison) % 2 == 0:
    col, row = (int(math.ceil(np.sqrt(len(comparison)))),int(math.ceil(np.sqrt(len(comparison)))))
if len(comparison) % 2 == 1:
   col, row = (int(math.ceil(np.sqrt(len(comparison)+1))),int(math.ceil(np.sqrt(len(comparison)+1))))

#Code where I try to iterate on the axes in my figures and set them using the .plot_timeseries() method

for graphs in range(len(comparison)):
    ax = comparison[graphs].plot_timeseries()
    fig.add_subplot(col,row,graphs+1)
```

This particular codes outputs a figure with the appropriate number of subplots. However the subplots are all empty. Also, it outputs every graphs generated by the `.plot_timeseries()` method separately.

I would like them to be put inside the subplots into one Figure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are the objects in `comparison` dataframes?

Comment: Hello thanks for the question. No they are actually `fmskill.comparison.PointComparer` objects from the FMskill library.

Comment: FMSkill is related to a MIKE hydrology model, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. It's a quite new library with few details on there github.io

Answer (score 0):

The last portion of code is backwards.

```py
# original
for graphs in range(len(comparison)):
    ax = comparison[graphs].plot_timeseries()
    fig.add_subplot(col,row,graphs+1)
```

Generate the axes object first, the pass it to the `plot_timeseries` function:

```py
for graphs in range(len(comparison)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(col, row, graphs+1)
    comparison[graphs].plot_timeseries(ax=ax)
```

Comment: I did try that before. The behaviour is exactly the same has before except this time the indivudals plots are plotted before the empty Multiplots figure.

Comment: Looks like FMSkill isn't implementing their plotting functions per Matplotlib's API recommendations.

Comment: That's what I thought, but figured that since I was able to get a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object that I should be able to put multiple of them into one figure.